# Why does latest postgresql jdbc driver returns zero rows when calling a function?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have this query

```
select * from mystoredproc(1) as (id integer, dat text)
```

If I use **postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc41.jar** the query returns 0 rows. But if I use **postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc4.jar** the query returns the correct rows.

my jdk is 1.7.0_u51

is this a bug in the new driver?

Comment: Please report the result of `select version();`

Comment: Are you certain the *only* thing you changed is the JDBC driver version? Also, what's the output of the query you write above in `psql`?

Comment: select versions(); returns
 PostgreSQL 9.3.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit

Comment: I just changed the jdbc jar and restarted the application. If I Call the query in psql it returns the rows.